# Template error when trying to create app with create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I looked at all the posts I can find where people have faced a similar issue, but I'm still having this problem:

```
jdwalters@JDs-MacBook-Air django-todo-react % npx create-react-app@5.0.0 frontend
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app@5.0.0
Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
Creating a new React app in /Users/jdwalters/Desktop/django-todo-react/frontend.

Installing packages. This might take a couple minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

added 1377 packages, and audited 1378 packages in 23s

163 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.
```

I have tried npx-clear-cache, completely uninstalled and reinstalled Node and npm, used which create-react-app to ensure that I didn't have a global install...I'm still running into this problem and I have no idea what to do.

**Edit**: I should add that as recently as a month ago I successfully created a React app using create-react-app, so I don't know why it's not working now.